Why does particle production during reheating begin after the inflation ends and inflaton reaches the minimum of its potential?
During reheating, when the inflaton interacts with other particles as described by the interaction part of the Lagrangian, why does particle production start only after the inflaton reaches the minimum of its potential, even in perturbative reheating? Why does not it happen during the slow roll phase?

It could happen, but depending on the model parameters, typically either:
(a) any energy density produced in Standard Model particles would decay away exponentially quickly due to the inflationary background, so that kind of particle production couldn't explain the matter we observe today,
or
(b) you would produce so much energy density in Standard Model particles that it sucks energy out of the inflaton and ends inflation.
